# Is Planck angular-frequency equal to 1/Planck-time or $2\pi$/Planck-time?

Tags: conventions, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, si-units

On wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units it states that the angular-frequency is equal to the inverse of the planck time.

$$
\begin{align}
\omega_p=\frac{1}{t_p}=\sqrt{\frac{c^5}{\hbar G}}
\end{align}
$$

However, on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency, it states that the definition of angular frequency is as follows

$$
\begin{align}
\omega=\frac{2\pi}{t}
\end{align}
$$

Thus, the Planck units, as they appear on wikipedia are wrong? Should the Planck angular frequency be

$$
\begin{align}
\omega_P=2\pi \sqrt{\frac{c^5}{\hbar G}}
\end{align}
$$

This $2\pi$ factor would actually carry to many other units. The power would be $2\pi c^4/G$, etc.?

Comment: It really doesn't matter, because the specific values of the Planck units have no meaning; it's an order of magnitude thing. In any case, there's no reason that just because $\omega = 2 \pi / t$ we should have $\omega_p = 2 \pi / t_p$, since $t_p$ is not the period of anything specific.

Comment: @knzhou It matters if your trying to balance your equations!

Comment: If you want, you can think of $t_p$ as being defined as "the time it takes for an oscillator with angular frequency $\omega_p$ to move by 1 radian", in which case $t_p = 1 / \omega_p$. The point is, $t_p$ doesn't really have a specific definition, you can choose the numerical factors however you want.

Answer (score 1):

the "$t$" in

$$ \omega=\frac{2\pi}{t} $$

is the **period** of oscillation.  the time required for one complete rotation of an angular vector.  it's not just any old time, but a specific time.  it is not the time it takes for the rotation of 1 radian.

where as the reason why $\omega_\mathrm{P}$ is used instead of "*ordinary*" frequency is because it's angular frequency (expressed as "$\omega$") that multiplies $\hbar$ and it is $\hbar$ that is normalized with Planck units.

i.e. 1 Planck Energy corresponds to a photon of **angular** frequency of 1, not to a photon with *ordinary* frequency (like "$f$" or "$\nu$") equal to 1.