# Considering subatomic particles constantly appear and disappear, can we say everything around us does too?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, vacuum, virtual-particles, popular-science

I'm very inexperienced in this area and could use some guidance, so I would really appreciate it if you could help satisfy my intellectual curiosity. I've come across the concept that subatomic particles spontaneously emerge from and vanish back into the void. Does this imply, or is it right to say that everything in the macroscopic world around us is continuously emerging and disappearing at the quantum level, millions of times per second?

Answer (score 5):

> ... subatomic particles spontaneously emerge from and vanish back into the void ...

This is only true of [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle). The protons, neutrons and electrons that make up ordinary matter have a continuous existence.

Comment: I would add that it is disputable to argue that virtual particles really exist. They could be considered just a *mathematical expedient* to compute quantities within a perturbative approach in flat spacetime.

Comment: @ValterMoretti All mathematical models are expedient.

Answer (score -1):

> I've come across the concept that...

First, the site rules here state "Accepted and/or actively researched theories", so may I suggest that you edit or comment to provide your source (even a forum post) that at least hints as to who had that idea (technically a hypothesis).

Second, I think that narrow formal theory shouldn't get the last word, because parts of your question yield to technical logic by engineers who now build quantum tools, but don't know quantum-level math. For example:

> millions of times per second?

If true, that's a frequency, which lets us ask a technical challenge question: What numerical hertz is that frequency?

One guess of mine is that it's the highest possible frequency, defined as a derived Plank unit.  The reason for my choice is that Planck units seem to represent the smallest parts of our particular meta-universe. Therefore those parts in motion logically have the highest frequencies, for which others present credible mathematics that I'll never understand.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units#Derived_units

I'll trial balloon 'the highest possible frequency' as being either the "Planck angular frequency", simple-math understandable as "An angular frequency of one radian per Planck time." (Apparently 6.28 Planck times per revolution or cycle.*)  Or, 'the highest possible frequency' might be the Plank ordinary frequency.  This frequency is reported as:

> "A repeating event that occurs once every Planck time, with a frequency of $~2.952\,\times\,10^{42}\,Hz$  This frequency is said to be the upper bound for the frequency of an electromagnetic ray or cosmic rays."  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Planck_frequency

The "Planck angular frequency" is debated at physics.stackexchange (below), but I didn't adequately understand the debate that seemed to be about more than one concept.*  [Is Planck angular-frequency equal to 1/Planck-time or $2\pi$/Planck-time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/379604/is-planck-angular-frequency-equal-to-1-planck-time-or-2-pi-planck-time))

"Planck angular frequency" was distinguished from "ordinary frequency".  I take "ordinary frequency" to mean like megahertz of ordinary FM-broadcast radio waves.  I don't know which definition is best suited to "emerging and disappearing at the quantum level", but I like the idea that particles are spinning if they do so.

Microwave radio engineering by Penzias and Wilson, 1964, accidentally discovered cosmic background static revealing the Big Bang.  Its bandwidth peaks at 160.23 GHz, sometimes misreported as a specific ordinary frequency.  This is a hint that the highest possible frequency is likely to be a probabilistic static, not a quantum sine-wave whistle.

> emerging and disappearing at the quantum level

I experience the many quantum physics explanations analogously to looking through a 20-faced icosahedron viewed from various angles.  Then I'm told, all of those analogous, rigid polygon faces and vertices are local concentrations of a fuzzy probability cloud. Therefore, some of the quantum explanations are valid under specified conditions, and worse, (IIRC) some of them are valid but not necessarily repeatable.

I think it's useful to mentally collect a lot of such quantum ideas, and eventually think about the logic of which ones seem to fit together like a cluster of soap bubbles.  Bubble clusters internally resemble fixed polyhedra, but flexibly accommodate to the shape of external surfaces.

> particles spontaneously emerge from and vanish back into the void

A specific related idea is that every particle has a theoretical half-life of once each.  For example :

"The best measurement yet of the lifetime of the electron suggests that a particle present today will probably still be around in 66,000 yottayears (6.6 × 1028 yr), which is about five-quintillion times the current age of the universe." (Not specifically reported as a half-life, but seems likely.) https://physicsworld.com/a/electron-lifetime-is-at-least-66000-yottayears/

@gandalf61 mentions the "continuous existence" of protons, neutrons and electrons.  For engineering purposes, that's true.

However, an electron half-life means probabilistically average, so there are a yotta-gazillion electrons with a much, much shorter half-life each.  Thus right now, a lot of them under (and in) our feet may be expiring into a photon and a neutrino.  Which if proven, (see above physicsworld.com URL) would violate the conservation of electrical charge and forcibly extend the Standard Model.

If proved true, it seems logically possible that some smaller subatomic pieces of the electron, say quarks, are half-life winking out "and disappearing at the quantum level".

Comment: How can I improve my answer? I count 3 downvotes with no explanation. Elsewhere on StackExchange, downvotes with comments are encouraged to allow the author to improve it.